# VisualStateManager messes up when I specify a default duration

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard, visualstatemanager

I'm trying to use the VisualStateManager to manage my control states. The following works fine and gives me a one second animation between states.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup Name="EditStates">

        <!-- Default transition time commented out
        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:2"></VisualTransition>
        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>-->

        <VisualState Name="Normal">
            <Storyboard>
                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ViewBorder"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="0"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderTransform"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" To="0" />
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>

        <VisualState Name="Editing">
            <Storyboard>
                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ViewBorder"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="100,0,100,100"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderTransform"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" To="1" />
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>

    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

However, if I uncomment the  transition code to try and set a 2 second animation time, it messes up spectacularly.

When "Editing" is set:

- The `DoubleAnimation` snaps to 1 instantly, with no animation.
- The `ThicknessAnimation` waits for 2 seconds and then animates over 1
  second

When "Normal" is set:

- The `ThicknessAnimation` snaps to 0 instantly, with no animation.
- The `DoubleAnimation` waits for 2 seconds and then animates over 1 second.

Can anyone explain what the heck is going on?

I've tried setting `Duration="0"` on all animations like certain samples seem to do, but all this does is remove the animation that does work. I still get the 2 second delays, then snapping rather than animating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've discovered enough to know this isn't anything to do with `GeneratedTransition`. I was just unlucky enough to be using two animations that `VisualStateManager` doesn't like.

Firstly, the animations within the `VisualStates` **should** have `Duration="0"`, since these are the steady states. I was removing them because it was the only way I was getting any kind of animation between states. However, what I was actually seeing was animation during the steady state period (ie **after** the transitions, hence the pause introduced when I added a default transition length).

The only reason I realised the above was by adding a `ColorAnimation`, which worked just fine.

My `DoubleAnimation` of `LayoutTransform.ScaleY` was failing because I was targeting the transform itself. Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828038/visualstatemanager-and-generated-transitions?rq=1), although the reason is unknown, I got it working by targeting the element instead:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Header" To="0" Duration="0"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" />
```

This just leaves my `ThicknessAnimation`, which is still just snapping to values. I have raised [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744989/visualstatemanager-cant-generate-transitions-for-thicknessanimations) for this now I have narrowed the problem down.