# VisualStateManager can't generate transitions for ThicknessAnimations

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, visualstatemanager

I have the following Visual States defined:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup Name="EditStates">

        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:2"/>
        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

        <VisualState Name="Editing" />                          
        <VisualState Name="Normal">
            <Storyboard>
                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ViewBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                <DoubleAnimation    Storyboard.TargetName="Header"     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                <ColorAnimation     Storyboard.TargetName="EditBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="Red" Duration="0"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>                                          

    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

The `DoubleAnimation` and `ColorAnimation` work fine, with `VisualStateManager` generating transition animations over 2 seconds for them.

However, the `ThicknessAnimation` does not animate. Instead it snaps to the finish value at the end of the transition period.

Is there any way to get `VisualStateManager` to generate transitions for it, or am I going to be forced to supply manual transitions?

Comment: I noticed the same. When you use Blend visually to drag an edge out it works internally using RenderTransform. Modifying a margin by hand has the same effect. I guess it's a bug or not implemented feature..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I analyzed the problem and fired up [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) and found that the `VisualStateManager` only supports the following animations:

- ColorAnimation
- DoubleAnimation
- PointAnimation

It's kind of crappy, because it's not documented anywhere.

To prove that it cannot generate the animations take a look at the reversed code of the `VisualStageManager.GenerateToAnimation` method. There is also a `VisualStageManager.GenerateFromAnimation` that supports the same subset of animations.

```
private static Timeline GenerateToAnimation(FrameworkElement root, Timeline timeline, IEasingFunction easingFunction, bool isEntering)
{
  Timeline destination = null;

  if (destination == null)
  {
    var targetColor = GetTargetColor(timeline, isEntering);
    if (targetColor.HasValue)
      destination = new ColorAnimation { To = targetColor, EasingFunction = easingFunction };
  }

  if (destination == null)
  {
    var targetDouble = GetTargetDouble(timeline, isEntering);
    if (targetDouble.HasValue)
        destination = new DoubleAnimation { To = targetDouble, EasingFunction = easingFunction };

  }

  if (destination == null)
  {
    var targetPoint = GetTargetPoint(timeline, isEntering);
    if (targetPoint.HasValue)
        destination = new PointAnimation { To = targetPoint, EasingFunction = easingFunction };
  }

  if (destination != null)
    CopyStoryboardTargetProperties(root, timeline, destination);

  return destination;
}
```

Bottomline... You can only use Color, Double or Point animations in the VisualStageManager. Revert to old-fashioned triggers if you need something else...

Comment: Annoying but useful! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your ThicknessAnimation statement is not complete, i search the flowing code sample from MSDN in the topic "ThicknessAnimation Class".

```
<ThicknessAnimation
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness"
                  Duration="0:0:1.5" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" From="1,1,1,1" To="28,14,28,14" />
```

Hope this could help you...

Comment: Thanks, but Unfortunately this is an animation. VisualStates require static storyboards since they set known states. I could define the above as a transition but this is what I'm trying to avoid.